# python create new dict key from the value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a array of hashes like:

```
detail = [{'name': 'Adam'}, {'name': 'Jackie'}]
```

Now what I want to do is create a new dict like:

```
{'name' : 'Sandra'}
```

What I did was:

```
for i in detail:
    for key_in_i in i:
        dict(key_in_i = 'Sandra')
```

What I would like to get is `{'Name': 'Sandra'}`. But if I do this I am getting `{'key_in_u': 'Sandra'}` because I have set the key as `key_in_i`. I don't know how to access the value of key from for loop to the new dict. If it was in Ruby I would have done `#{key_in_i}` and it would have given me the required value. I also tried `new_dict = dict("%s" %key = i[key])` but it gives me error `key cannot be the expression`. I would be thankful if anyone could help me solve this issue!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest solution in this particular case is

```
for i in detail:
    print dict.fromkeys(i, "Sandra")
```

You could also use a dictionary literal:

```
for i in detail:
    for key_in_i in i:
        {key_in_i: "Sandra"}
```

(Not sure what you are actually trying to achieve since your example code is effectively doing nothing.)

Comment: Thanks the 2nd solution worked! I was just trying to be specific with simple example! :)